# EN 61010 Creepage and Clearance questions

Tags: clearance, creepage

My PCB has to meet EN 61010 safety standard and i had a question regarding creepage and clearance values.

Has anyone got any experience applying this standard and when the creepage and clearance values in section 6.7 are to be used?
[image]

The standard states that accessible parts should be prevented from becoming hazardous live by the below means, and that creepage and clearances in 6.7 should be adhered to if an enclosure is being used.

Our system is powered from a 24V battery and thus does not meet the requirements of a 'hazardous live' part as defined in the standard. As our product is never at the voltage level to become hazardous live, do we need to meet creepage and clearance rules? or any of the primary protection rules for that matter?

Any help with this is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you not able to meet 0.5mm?

Comment: Hi, it’s  not impossible to change just not ideal if it can be avoided.

Comment: The answer is going to rely on more details: Plastic box, metal box, power level, is UL certification needed, hazardous environment?

Comment: Hi, we use a Hammond plastic enclosure ip68 rated shown here : https://www.hammfg.com/part/1555VAL2GY Electronics draw 3W of power. UL certification is not needed as far as I am aware. It is not used in a hazardous environment.

Comment: If you have no voltages higher than your battery voltage, (I.e. no boost or flybacks, etc.) I'm pretty sure that qualifies as SELV and you don't need to worry about creepage and clearance.  If there's a potential for high current to flow you may still need to limit access.

Comment: At low voltage, low power, plastic sealed enclosure, I think you can do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the advice